# For a Thermo-Calc database, is it possible to view the equation/parameters of the Gibbs free energy models?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, material-science, computational-physics

I want to get the equations that model free energy for a given phase in a given alloy system (see attached image). I do ***not*** just want to get values of free energy for specific compositions. Is it possible to extract the equations themselves from a Thermo-Calc database? Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this in TC_Python, but if it's only possible in Console Mode I could work with that.

Example Output I found (but don't know the code used to generate it):

```
        PARAMETER G(HCP_A3,CO:VA;0)  298.15  +GHSERCO;,,N !
        PARAMETER G(HCP_A3,NI:VA;0)  298.15  +GHCPNI;,,N !
        FUNCTION GHSERCO    298.15  +310.241+133.36601*T
        -25.0861*T*LN(T)-.002654739*T**2-1.7348E-07*T**3
        +72527*T**(-1)  1768.0  Y  -17197.666+253.28374*T
        -40.5*T*LN(T)+9.3488E+30*T**(-9);,,   N !
        FUNCTION GHSERNI    298.15  -5179.159+117.854*T
        -22.096*T*LN(T)-.0048407*T**2;
        1728.0  Y  -27840.655+279.135*T-43.1*T*LN(T)
        +1.12754E+31*T**(-9);,,  N   !
        PARAMETER L(HCP_A3,CO,NI:VA;0)  298.15  -1620-.385*T;,,N !
        PARAMETER TC(HCP_A3,CO:VA;0)  298.15  +1396;,,N !
        PARAMETER BMAGN(HCP_A3,CO:VA;0)  298.15  1.35;,,N !
        PARAMETER TC(HCP_A3,NI:VA;0)  298.15  633;,,N !
        PARAMETER BMAGN(HCP_A3,NI:VA;0)  298.15  .52;,,N !
        PARAMETER TC(HCP_A3,CO,NI:VA;0)  298.15  411;,,N !
        PARAMETER TC(HCP_A3,CO,NI:VA;1)  298.15  -99;,,N!
        PARAMETER BMAGN(HCP_A3,CO,NI:VA;0)  298.15  1.046;,,N !
        PARAMETER BMAGN(HCP_A3,CO,NI:VA;1)  298.15  .165;,,N !
```

Comment: So, yes, all the information you need is right there. With perhaps a bit of perusal of Dinsdale’s paper and some other Calphad literature to get the gist of it.

Comment: @JonCuster Please Elaborate

Comment: Try Yubi Zhang et al., Calphad 33 405-414 (2009), and AT Dinsdale, Calphad 15(4) 317-425 (1991).